# Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?

Tags: asp.net, lado-do-cliente, lado-do-servidor

Estou estudando ASP.NET através de um livro chamado *Professional: ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB* e em vários momentos o autor fala sobre código *client-side* e *server-side*, gostaria de saber a diferença.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Server-side* diz respeito ao lado do servidor (seu servidor de aplicação, ex: [IIS](http://www.iis.net/)).
*Client-side* diz respeito ao lado do cliente (ex: um web-browser).

A interação funciona da seguinte forma: **Servidor ← →  Cliente ← →  Usuário**

- O **servidor** fornece para o **cliente** uma *saída*: ele serve a página desejada ou arquivos (download).
- O **servidor** interpreta a *entrada* do **cliente**: o cliente envia informações (formulário) para o servidor e arquivos (upload).
- O **cliente** fornece para o **usuário** uma *saída*: a página renderizada que ele obteve do servidor (html).
- O **cliente** interpreta a *entrada* do **usuário**: o usuário entra com diferentes dados no cliente (e este eventualmente envia-os ao servidor).

Exemplo:

1. **Usuário →  Cliente**: O usuário entra com o endereço http://www.google.com em seu web browser.
2. **Cliente →  Servidor**: Então o cliente realiza a requisação da página ao servidor de google.com.
3. **Servidor →  Cliente**: O servidor recebe a requisição, obtém a página e envia ao cliente.
4. **Cliente →  Usuário**: O cliente renderiza a página (HTML) recebida pelo servidor e exibe ao usuário.
5. **Usuário →  Cliente**: O usuário entra com uma pesquisa no campo de pesquisas da página e clica em "Pesquisar".
6. **Cliente →  Servidor**: O cliente envia a requisição com o termo de busca informado pelo usuário.
7. **Servidor →  Cliente**: O servidor monta a página com os resultados da pesquisa e envia para o cliente.
8. **Cliente →  Usuário**: O cliente, ao receber do servidor a página com os resultados da pesquisa, renderiza a nova página e exibe para o usuário.

*E assim em diante...*

Comment: Por que há tantos votos negativos nas duas melhores respostas? Alias, por que há tantos votos negativos em todas as respostas aqui? (sobre essa resposta, "⟶" é uma seta? não é renderizado corretamente aqui)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Não consigo visualizar aqui, tem tantos downvotes assim..? :o

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Sim é uma seta. Qual browser você está utilizando? Se não renderizar na maioria do browser do pessoal eu troco para simplesmente `->`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Concordo! A pergunta pode ser simples, mas isso não justifica "punir" quem responde. Já fiz [perguntas simples](http://serverfault.com/q/443038/106111) antes - motivadas somente pela barreira da linguagem - e já respondi outras tantas também, sem ter esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Aqui também não está aparecendo a seta (Chrome).

Comment: Dada a quantidade de respostas corretas mas curtas demais eu cheguei a pensar em escrever algo mais completo com um exemplo de fluxo, mas o @talles já se adiantou. Alguém mais acha que a resposta correta deveria ser esta?

Comment: Alterei para uma seta *teoricamente* "HTML safe". Se não funcionar avisem. Valeu :)

Comment: Poderia falar alguma coisa sobre client-side. Penso que são duas formas, uma é quando a requisição não vai até o servidor (exemplo, quando o usuário clica em algo que muda a cor de um botão ou outro widget qualquer, ou seja, basta fazer um JavaScript que altere a cor do objeto em questão) ou então quando se trata de uma requisição Ajax que objetiva alterar um pedaço do DOM (e não a página inteira) com dados trazidos do servidor. Essa última é a que tenho mais dificuldade de visualizar por falta de experiência com desenvolvimento web e por isso busco esclarecimento em perguntas do SO como esta.

Answer (score 14):

A diferença simplesmente é onde o código será executado: no servidor onde o ASP.NET está instalado (*server-side*) ou no navegador a partir do qual o sistema será acessado (*client-side*).

Embora seja possível se desenvolver uma aplicação/site exclusivamente utilizando HTML e CSS **no lado cliente** (gerando as páginas dinamicamente no servidor, e usando somente links e/ou formulários para entrada de dados), muitas vezes é desejável que certo código seja executado no navegador do usuário, por exemplo para fins de validação ou melhoria de usabilidade. Nesse caso, o trecho relevante deve ser escrito em - ou convertido para - JavaScript, que é a única linguagem universalmente aceita pelos navegadores. Outras formas de código cliente poderiam ser plugins como Flash ou Java.

Cabe lembrar que o **agente do usuário** não precisa nem necessariamente ser um navegador (*browser*) - qualquer aplicação que implemente o lado cliente do protocolo HTTP pode interagir com o servidor de aplicação (sem necessariamente oferecer suporte a JavaScript).

Comment: "respondida 55 segs atrás", já com -2 votos. Putz, tem gente por aqui que é ninja na hora de votar contra. Vamos com calma pessoal.

Comment: Qual é exatamente a diferença entre minha resposta e as duas outras nessa página? Seria o fato de eu não ter mencionado que o código cliente é [ou é convertido para] JavaScript? Ou tem algo mais de errado nessa resposta? Comentem!

Comment: Aplicação somente com HTML e CSS? Esses recursos servem para criar páginas estáticas, não aplicações, e mesmo um site simples, sem utilizar uma linguagem server-side, requerem o mínimo de JS, até mesmo para definir uma regra CSS para algum browser específico por exemplo...

Comment: @KennyRafael oi? É perfeitamente possível criar uma aplicação usando só HTML e CSS **no lado cliente**. Basta que essas páginas sejam geradas dinamicamente pelo servidor e contenham links e/ou formulários...

Comment: Se ela está sendo gerada DINAMICAMENTE pelo servidor, é por que tem alguma linguagem rodando por trás, se é apenas conteúdo estático, não é uma aplicação, uma aplicação tem funcionalidades, por mais simples que sejam, o HTML e o CSS podem fazer parte de uma aplicação, nunca vão SER a aplicação.

Comment: @KennyRafael E o que exatamente eu estou dizendo que contradiz com o que você está dizendo?!!! Atualizei minha resposta pra ver se fica mais claro... :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr , vale a pena mencionar que Java ou Flash para interfaces ricas estão em desuso atualmente?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu pedi uma complementação na resposta aceita que se você quiser fazer também na sua resposta, sinta-se à vontade. :)

Answer (score 2):

Client-side = executa do lado do cliente, ex.: Javascript.

Server-side = executa no servidor, ex.: PHP, C#, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side é aquele que roda do lado do cliente(Ex. Javascript), ou seja, no browser do usuário, Server-side roda no servidor (Ex. PHP, JAVA, .NET...)