# Expressão regular para validação de e-mail

Tags: javascript, regex, validação, email

Estou tentando criar uma expressão regular par validar um e-mail qualquer, escrevi a expressão abaixo, mas ela não está funcionando do jeito esperado:

```javascript
var emailRegex = /^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.([a-z]+)?$/i;
```

O que esperava de cada trecho:

- `[a-z0-9.]+` - parte antes do `@` do e-mail, nome do usuário;
- `@` - caractere de arroba obrigatório;
- `[a-z0-9]+` - parte depois do `@` do e-mail, nome do provedor;
- `\.` - caractere de ponto depois do nome do provedor;
- `[a-z]+` - geralmente onde é colocado o `.com`;
- `\.` - caractere de ponto depois do `.com`, só deveria ser obrigatório caso haja por exemplo um `.br` ou a abreviação de qualquer outro país no final do e-mail;
- `([a-z]+)?` - geralmente onde é colocado a abreviação do país.

Como testei a expressão:

```
const emailRegex = /^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]?$/i
console.log('foo.bar@gmail.com =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bar@gmail.com'))
console.log('foo.bar@gmail.com.br =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bar@gmail.com.br'))
console.log('foo.bar@gmail.com.br.br =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bar@gmail.com.br.br'))
console.log('foo.bar@gmail. =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bar@gmail.'))
console.log('foo.bar@gmailcom =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bar@gmailcom'))
console.log('foo.bargmail.com =>', emailRegex.test('foo.bargmail.com'))
console.log('@gmail.com =>', emailRegex.test('@gmail.com'))
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa aceitar que não será capaz de processar todos os e-mails possíveis. A especificação deles é longa e complicada. Por exemplo, aqui está uma regex que aceita todos os emails e nada mais: [http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html](http://ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Tendo isso em mente, parte-se para fazer uma regex que possa acertar *na maioria* dos casos.

```js
/^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.([a-z]+)?$/i
```

[(regexplained)](http://tinyurl.com/jvplhfk)

Seu erro aqui foi apenas o de não incluir o último `\.` dentro dos parênteses. Fazendo isso tenho esse resultado:

```
foo.bar@gmail.com       true
foo.bar@gmail.com.br    true
foo.bar@gmail.com.br.br false
foo.bar@gmail.          false
foo.bar@gmailcom        false
foo.bargmail.com        false
@gmail.com                 false
```

Que acredito ser o que você busca. Mas isso vai falhar em diversos outros casos. Como se o email incluir *underlines* ou `+`, ou se o dominio incluir muitos caracteres (como alguns do governo `alguem@orgao.uf.gov.br`, já tive problemas com esses).

Uma sugestão mais completa, vinda da [especificação do HTML5 pela W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address):

> The following JavaScript- and Perl-compatible regular expression is an implementation of the above definition.

> ```
> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
> ```

[(regexplained)](http://tinyurl.com/mlwavo8)

Lembre-se que validações em [*client-side*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferenca-entre-codigo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web/612#612) não devem ser consideradas confiáveis, especialmente em javascript, pois o usuário pode alterar o código e burlar a validação. Deve sempre existir uma validação feita pelo servidor, geralmente enviando um e-mail de confirmação. Usualmente a validação no cliente é usada apenas para melhorar a experiencia de usuário, mostrando o que está errado sem a demora de esperar uma resposta do servidor.

Comment: +1 Estava para postar a mesma resposta, mas você foi mais rápido... :) Nesse caso, deixo aqui apenas uma [referência adicional](http://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php), com mais opções de regexes e um teste extensivo dos seus falsos positivos e negativos.

Comment: Sugiro colocar um `/g` no final da expressão para evitar que um texto qualquer seja injetado no final da String. Exemplo: `"zignd.igor@gmail.com xyz"` é aceito sem o `g`.

Comment: @utluiz o `^` e `$` já não dariam conta desde caso? Testei com `"a@a.com"` e `"a@a.com x"`, o primeiro passa enquanto que o segundo falha. Não entendi.

Comment: Tem razão, Guilherme. Deveria dar conta. Mas testei a expressão sugerida (a segunda) e aceitou um e-mail com espaço. [Veja aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/59djQ/). Nem com o `g` deu certo. Tem algo de errado com essa expressão.

Comment: @utluiz Parece que você mudou o texto sendo mostrado mas não a string usada no `regex.test()`. [Testei aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/UwGwL/), funciona sem problemas.

Comment: É verdade, esqueci de mudar nos demais locais. Só mais uma coisa: `zignd.igor@gmailcom` deveria ser válido?

Comment: Bom... nunca vi nada assim, mas o link de @mgibsonbr clama que `test@example` e `first.last@com` são válidos. Então esse deve ser também.

Comment: Isso deve ter alguma coisa a ver com essa mudança recente nos domínios de nível mais alto (*top level domains*). Antes era uma lista restrita - e exigia ao menos um subdomínio - mas agora ele aceita qualquer coisa (pra quem pagar o preço).

Comment: +1 pelo site regexplained.

Comment: Recomendo usar a regex do http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html, uma vez que a simplificação vai deixar de fora emails válidos que estão em uso atualmente. Inclusive email de domínios ou nome de usuários que contenham hífen `-`.

Comment: @motobói A expressão sugerida pelo W3C engloba os que contém hífen. Além disso não há necessidade de incluir uma expressão tão grande para casos praticamente não usados. A da W3C falha em emails que contém aspas ou comentários ou cujo domínio é um IPv6. Quem usa um e-mail assim não espera realmente que vá passar por validadores.

Comment: A REGEX do exemplo tem um ponto final fora do parênteses quando na verdade esse ponto deveria estar dentro do parênteses por ser opcional. Mudar `\.(` para `(\.` na ocorrência do segundo ponto.

Answer (score 15):

## Dificuldades na Validação de E-mails

Validar e-mails com RegEx, ainda mais via JavaScript, pode ser uma faca de dois gumes. E-mails válidos podem ser rejeitados e inválidos podem ser aceitos na maioria das expressões usadas comumente nos sites mundo afora.

Por outro lado, é importante entender que não é necessário, nem é recomendável, validar um e-mail muito rigidamente, afinal somente saberemos se ele é verdadeiramente válido quando enviarmos um e-mail para o endereço em questão.

Uma discussão interessante sobre validação de e-mail pode ser encontrada [neste link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

## Validação com Regex

Uma expressão regular que valida adequadamente um e-mail de acordo com a definição oficial de e-mails pode ser encontrada [neste link](http://ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Entretanto, ela é muito complexa e provavelmente não suportada pelas *engines* de Javascript.

Uma simplificação pode ser encontrada no artigo citado anteriormente (primeiro link), que seria:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/gi
```

Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7hMt/1/).

Note que o sufixo `/gi` ao final. O `i` faz com que e-mails com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas sejam aceitos. O `g` faz com que a expressão verifique a String como um todo. Sem o `g`, um e-mail como `foo.bar@gmail.com foo.bar@gmail.com` seria aceito.

## Ajustando a Expressão Regular da Pergunta

Quanto à expressão original da pergunta, um pequeno ajuste faria ela funcionar:

```
/^[a-z0-9.]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)?$/i
```

Note que o último parêntesis aberto está agora antes do último caractere de ponto final, que também deve ser opcional. Por outro lado, esta expressão terá muitos falsos-positivos. A expressão anterior é mais adequada.

Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3e7/1/).

## Conclusão

A expressão regular proposta na pergunta pode ser facilmente corrigida, mas ela inviabilizará e-mails válidos de serem aceitos. A outra expressão citada mais acima é mais recomendada. Embora e-mails como `teste@gmail.com.br.br` sejam aceitos, eles são, em teoria, perfeitamente válidos.

Comment: Sugiro substituir o `?` no último trecho por `*`, para suportar um número ilimitado de sub-domínios: `(\.[a-z]+)*` Menos falsos negativos... (ou melhor ainda, junte o `\.[a-z]+` anterior a ele, resultando em `(\.[a-z]+)+`)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Concordo, mas se está se referindo à seção "Ajustando a Expressão Regular da Pergunta", isso foi apenas para fazer a expressão funcionar no teste. A expressão recomendada mais acima já aceita subdomínios ilimitados.

Answer (score 7):

Crie uma função com o nome exemplo: `validEmail`. Essa função deve receber o e-mail por parâmetro e verificar se é um e-mail válido.

O nome do usuário (antes do arroba), pode ser qualquer caractere alfanumérico, incluindo o underscore, sinal de "+" e o ponto

Após o arroba, o domínio pode conter somente caracteres alfanuméricos e o underscore;

Para a extensão, o domínio deve vir seguido de um ponto, e no mínimo 2 caracteres alfanuméricos;

O final do domínio é opcional, mas se existir, deve começar com um ponto, seguido de no máximo 2 caracteres alfanuméricos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após as devidas explicações segue o código javascript da função com o regex

```
function validEmail(email){
    return /^[\w+.]+@\w+\.\w{2,}(?:\.\w{2})?$/.test(email)
}
```

Essa função ira retornar true ou false

Answer (score 6):

Duas expressões que uso sem problema são:

```
"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+).(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"

"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
```

Dessa maneira:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email)
{
 var reg = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/
 if (reg.test(email)){
 return true; }
 else{
 return false;
 }
} 
</script>
```

Porém, adianto que não é mais interessante utilizar essas validações, pois elas erram muito com os novos domínios e extensões. Aconselho você a dar uma olhada no [artigo do Douglas Lovell](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,0), que é para PHP mas facilmente se converte para JS.

Answer (score 0):

Essa expressão me satisfaz:

```
let email = "test@email.com";
let regex_validation = /^([a-z]){1,}([a-z0-9._-]){1,}([@]){1}([a-z]){2,}([.]){1}([a-z]){2,}([.]?){1}([a-z]?){2,}$/i;
console.log("É email válido? Resposta: " + regex_validation.test(email));
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse código pode ser uma solução para a pergunta, mas sua resposta pode ser melhor se você incluir uma explicação sobre os principais pontos do código. O objetivo não é ajudar apenas quem fez a pergunta, mas os próximos visitantes também. Leia mais em [Respostas apenas com código - O que fazer?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/100416).

Answer (score -1):

Com syntax do HTML5 também é possível fazer uma validação no HTML mesmo definindo o type do input para "email".

```html
<input type="email" name="email"/>
```

Answer (score -5):

Pode usar sem medo, funciona até em Typescript.

```
[A-Za-z0-9\\._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\..(\\.[A-Za-z]+)*
```