# Verificacao de email em Java

Tags: java, regex, email

Estou fazendo um teste simples para verificar se o usuario digitou um email valido. So que estou com erro de **sintaxe no token "@" invalido AssignmentOperator.**

Codigo da classe principal:

```
public class Email {

static String email = "pessoa@teste.com.br";

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public static void validarEmail(){

    //Verifica a posicao do @ no emal.
    int validarEmail = email.indexOf("@");
    //System.out.println(validarEmail);

}

public static void obterNome(){

    //Seleciona o que esta escrito antes do @.
    String obterNome = email.substring(0, 6);
    //System.out.println(obterNome);

}
```

Classe que verifica o Email:

```
public class VerificaEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Email e = new Email();

    //Verifica se o Email e valido.
boolean b = e.validarEmail(pessoa@teste.com.br);
    if(!b)
        System.out.println("Email Inválido");
    else
        System.out.println("Email Válido");

// Imprime o que esta antes do @.
String nome = e.obterNome(pessoa@teste.com.br);
System.out.println(nome);

}
```

Comment: Se eu colocar em String e o email entre aspas nao funciona tbm.

Comment: Mas o erro quando o email (nas duas chamadas dentro de `VerificaEmail`) está entre aspas é diferente, certo?

Comment: se eu colocar os emails da classe `verificaEmail` entre aspas ele apresenta o seguinte erro **- teste cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error on token "@", invalid AssignmentOperator
 - pessoa cannot be resolved to a variable
 - The method validarEmail() in the type Email is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String)**
E eles e o mesmo email da classe principal.

Comment: "pessoa cannot be resolved to a variable" esse erro é justamente pq vc tá passando sem as aspas, deveria ser `boolean b = e.validarEmail("pessoa@teste.com.br");`

Comment: @Math Ja tentei fazer desse jeito com as aspas mais da erro tbm

Comment: Mas pelo menos deve ser outro erro, não é não?

Comment: @re22 Na verdade o jeito que ele colocou dava certo mais acabei descobrindo o que estava causando o erro. E utilizei outros metodos para solucionar o problema. Mas lembrando que o jeito que ele colocou tbm funciona so que e mais complexo e o meu ficou mais facil.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A melhor maneira de você validar um email é aplicar uma expressão regular.

**Pattern como membro estático**

na sua classe Email crie um membro privado estático e final do tipo Pattern

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

**Use um Matcher dentro do seu método validar email**

```
public static boolean validarEmail(String email){
    Matcher matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
 }
```

Note que é melhor deixar o Pattern como mebro estático e já compilado assim, você não precisa criar um novo a cada nova validação, você ganha em ***performance***

**Precisa que seja compliance com RFC822?**

[Exemplo RFC822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email/13013056#13013056)

****Note que eu mudei o retorno do seu método para boolen, assim faz mais sentido para classes clientes chamarem seu método

Comment: Só uma nota: validação de e-mail com regex não é 100% seguro, pois não é totalmente *compliant* com a especificação (RFC). Podem ocorrer falsos positivos e falsos negativos, então a dica é sempre testar com cuidado para que a solução seja *boa o suficiente* para atender suas necessidades. Para maiores detalhes, ver [esta outra questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1386/227).

Comment: Legal, valeu pela dica @utluiz Eu coloqueio uma referencia para antender a este caso do RFC. Caso necessário, solicite que faço uma tradução completa da resposta em inglês. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Sua classe Email precisa de um metodo Main? Se você quer gravar nela o email informado um construtor faria mais sentido.

```
public class Email {

static String email;

public Email(String email){
    this.email = email;
}  

//public static void validarEmail(){
public boolean validarEmail()
    //Verifica a posicao do @ no emal.
    //int validarEmail = this.email.indexOf("@");
    //System.out.println(validarEmail);

    return ( this.email.indexOf('@') > 0 );    
}

public static String obterNome(){

    //Seleciona o que esta escrito antes do @.
    return this.email.substring(0, this.email.indexOf('@'));
    //System.out.println(obterNome);

}
```

Ai na outra classe:

```
public class VerificaEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Email e = new Email("pessoa@teste.com.br");

    //Verifica se o Email e valido.
    if(!e.validarEmail())
        System.out.println("Email Inválido");
    else
        System.out.println("Email Válido");


    System.out.println(e.obterNome());

}
```

Comment: Utilizei seu código so que ainda tenho alguns erros que nao estou conseguindo solucionar. Nas linhas `return obterNome = this.email.substring(0, this.email.indexOf('@'));` 
`Email e = new Email("pessoa@teste.com.br");` 
`if(!e.validarEmail())`
`String nome = e.ObterNome("pessoa@teste.com.br");`.

Comment: Estava incorreto, editei o codigo aqui direto no post, então não percebi. Mas veja que a solução proposta pelo @Filipe Gonzaga Miranda eh muito mais interessante. O que fiz aqui foi apenas um ajuste no seu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei encontrando uma forma mais simples para solucionar meus erros segue o codigo:

***Classe Email:**

`public class Email {`

```
public static String email = "pessoa@teste.com.br";
public static String Nome;
public static int indiceEmail;

public static boolean validarEmail(){

    //Verifica se o email possui o @.
    indiceEmail = email.indexOf('@');
    if (indiceEmail > 0)
        return(true);
    else
        return(false);  

}

public static String obterNome(){

    if (indiceEmail > 0)
        return Nome = email.substring(0, indiceEmail);
    else
        return("Erro!");        

}
```

**Classe principal:**

`public class VerificaEmail {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Email e = new Email();      

//Verifica se o Email e valido.
boolean b = e.validarEmail();
    if(!b)
        System.out.println("Email Inválido");
    else
        System.out.println("Email Válido");

// Imprime o que esta antes do @.
String nome = e.obterNome();
System.out.println(nome);

}
```

Dessa forma ficou mais simples e melhor de entender e sem alterar o intenção do autor.