# Como inserir dados com JSON e MVC5

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, json.net

Tenho uma tela de cadastro, onde o usuário poderá inserir quantos emails quiser em cada registro. Para isso, na minha View tenho o seguinte código

```
<div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" id="btnAddEmail">Adicionar</button>
        <table id="tblEmails">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>#</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAddEmail").click(function () {
                $("#tblEmails tbody").append("<tr>" +
                "<td></td>" +
                "<td><input id='txtEmail'></td>" +
                "<td class='bto'><button type='button'>Salvar</button></td></tr>");
            });
```

quando eu clico em Adicionar, aparece uma nova row na table com o campo para inserir um novo email com o botao Salvar.

Como faço para acionar esse botão Salvar gerado dinamicamente e passar os dados inseridos para o meu Model, e essa row com input sumisse para dar lugar a uma row apenas com label mostrando o ultimo email adicionado?

Comment: você tem o Controller feito? e você quer enviar todos os e-mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer esse código, deve construir varias funções `javascript` uma para adicionar o `input`, uma para salvar e enviar as informações `Server-Side`, uma para substituir o `input` por um `span` e outra para sumir com o botão, inclusive também fiz um botão cancelar se quiser cancelar a ação de criar um novo e-mail.

***Exemplo minimo:***

Código da `View`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" id="btnAddEmail">Adicionar</button>
    <table id="tblEmails">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Email</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script>
        var isEmail = function (value)
        {
            var t = /^[a-z0-9.]+@@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+\.([a-z]+)?$/i;
            return t.test(value);
        }
        var uniqid = function () {
            return (new Date().getTime()
                + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000)
                    + 1)).toString(16);
        };
        function addEmail()
        {
            var id = uniqid();
            var u = 'txt' + id;
            var t = 'tr' + id;
            var s = '<tr id=\'' + t + '\'><td></td>';
            s = s + '<td><input name="email" id="' + u + '" required></td>';
            s = s + '<td class="bto">';
            s = s + '<button type="button" 
                      onclick="saveEmail(\'' + u + '\')">Salvar</button>';
            s = s + '<button type="button" 
                      onclick="cancelEmail(\'' + t + '\')">Cancelar</button>';
            s = s + '</td ></tr>';
            $("#tblEmails tbody").append(s);

        }
        function saveEmail(id) {
            var obj = document.getElementById(id);
            if (obj.value != "" && isEmail(obj.value)) {
                $.post("@Url.Action("Create", "Emails")", { email: obj.value },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.status) {
                            replaceLabelAndButton(obj);
                        }
                    }, 'json');

                return true;
            }
            alert("Digite o e-mail corretamente");
            obj.focus();
            return false;
        }
        function cancelEmail(id) {
            jQuery(document.getElementById(id)).remove();
        }
        function replaceLabelAndButton(obj) {
            jQuery(obj)
                .parent()
                .next()
                .html('');
            jQuery(obj)
                .parent()
                .html('<span>' + obj.value + '</span>');
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAddEmail").click(function () {
                addEmail();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Código do `Controller`:

Nesse código do `controller` é só ter o mesmo nome do `input` (*que no caso foi e-mail*) para resgatar as informações e assim fazer o código de gravação.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class EmailsController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult Create(string email)
        {
            var c = email;
            return Json(new { status = true });
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [jQuery – Métodos .parent(), .parents() e .closest()](http://blog.astraube.eti.br/2012/03/jquery-metodos-parent-parents-e-closest/)
- [Expressão regular para validação de e-mail](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1386/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-e-mail)
- [JQuery - siblings based on next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419730/jquery-siblings-based-on-next)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Pela sua pergunta, sua dificuldade está em montar esse front-end, então segue um exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnAddEmail").click(function () {
      $("#tblEmails tbody").append("<tr>" +
      "<td></td>" +
      "<td><input name='txtEmail'></td>" +
      "<td><button type='button' class='bt-salvar'>Salvar</button></td></tr>");
  });
  
  // Evento click do botão gerado dinamicamente
  $(document).on('click', '.bt-salvar', function() {
  
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    
    // Recupera o valor do campo
    var email = $tr.find('[name="txtEmail"]').val();
    
    // Executa o ajax
    /*$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ".",
      data: {email: email},
      success: callback_success,
      error: function() {
        alert('Falha ao salvar');
      }
    });*/
    callback_success();
    
    function callback_success() {
      alert('Registro salvo com sucesso');
      $tr.remove();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" id="btnAddEmail">Adicionar</button>
    <table id="tblEmails">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Ação</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Deixei o ajax comentado e fiz a chamada do callback diretamente apenas para efeito de exemplificação. Na sua aplicação você descomenta o ajax e configura a url correta.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Diego , sua solução complementou a solução que o Virgilio passou. Ambas ajudaram muito!