# Como extrair substring em array de strings com JavaScript utilizando match?

Tags: javascript, array, string, regex, substring

Tenho que manipular um dado no seguinte formato:
`["nome <email desse nome>"]`, um array com várias strings nesse mesmo formato. Quero extrair em um outro array apenas os emails, sem as `<>`

Já tentei converter para array simples e usar o método `String.match()` do JS com a regexp `\<(.*)\>`, mas o retorno é outro array e com outros dados que são inúteis pra mim.

Alguma dica de como fazer de uma forma que seja minimamente performático?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O resultado que você informou é esperado, veja:

> Já tentei converter para array simples e usar o `String.match()` do JS com a regexp `<(.*)>`, mas o retorno é outro array e com outros dados que são inúteis pra mim.

[Veja a documentação do `match`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) De fato, retorna-se um array com diversas outras informações. Uma dessas informações é exatamente o que você precisa — o valor capturado pelo grupo que está na regex.

Portanto, você precisa de extrair o valor do grupo de captura do array retornado pelo `match`. Como você só tem um grupo de captura, corresponde ao segundo elemento da lista retornada (já que o primeiro corresponde à string testada).

Um exemplo simples:

```js
const str = 'John Doe <john.doe@prov.com>';
const match = str.match(/<(.*)>/);
console.log(match[1]); // somente o e-mail (capturado pelo 1º e único grupo)
```

No caso de um array de strings, a cada uma das quais será invocado `match`, você pode utilizar um `map`. Assim:

```js
const strs = [
  'foo <foo@prov.com>',
  'bar <bar@prov.com>',
  'baz <baz@prov.com>',
  'invalid'
];

const emails = strs.map((str) => {
  return str.match(/<(.*)>/)?.[1];
});
console.log(emails);
```

O que ocorre acima é simples: para cada uma das strings da lista, mapeamos ao segundo elemento do array retornado pelo `match`. Veja mais sobre o [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) aqui.

Veja que, no caso da string não corresponder à expressão regular, `match` retorna `null` (tal como ocorreu na última string do array acima). Nesse tipo de situação, o JavaScript lançaria um erro uma vez que tentássemos indexar `1` em `null`. Para resolver isso, utilizei o [encadeamento opcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486360/69296) (que retorna `undefined`) em casos como esse. Você, claro, pode tratar essas situações de modo diferente.

Uma outra opção, sem usar expressão regular, é obter o índice do primeiro `<` e retornar a *substring* existente até o penúltimo caractere, que deve, obrigatoriamente, ser seguido de `>`. Assim:

```js
function getEmail(str) {
  const start = str.indexOf('<');
  if (start === -1) return undefined;

  const end = str.length - 1;
  if (str[end] !== '>') return undefined;

  return str.substring(start + 1, end);
}

const strs = [
  'foo <foo@prov.com>',
  'bar <bar@prov.com>',
  'baz <baz@prov.com>',
  'invalid'
];

const emails = strs.map(getEmail);
console.log(emails);
```

Claro que, por não utilizar expressão regular, esse último código será *bem* mais rápido. Perde-se, todavia, em expressividade e em tamanho de implementação. Expressão regular, nesse caso, parece-me ser mais simples.

---

E ainda tem o ponto sobre a validade do e-mail, mas aí já é [outro assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1386/69296) – e *spoiler*: bem mais complexo.

Comment: Outra opção é trocar a regex para `/<([^>]+)>/` - o `[^>]` (qualquer caractere que não seja `>`) garante que ela vai parar quando encontrar o `>`, o que não acontece com o ponto, pois ele corresponde a qualquer caractere, inclusive o `>`, então ele primeiro vai até o fim da string e depois vai voltando (*backtracking*) até encontrar o `>` (tudo bem que nesse caso ele está no final e não será tão pior assim, mas mesmo assim fica um "tiquinho" mais rápido: https://jsbench.me/xeksi6olml/1)

Answer (score 2):

> *Alguma dica de como fazer de uma forma que seja minimamente performático*

Sempre que você quer algo "performático", regex *geralmente* não está entre as primeiras opções (por uma série de motivos, como [o fato da *engine* precisar compilar a expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486263/112052) e vários outros detalhes internos de funcionamento que geram um *overhead* enorme).

Claro que para strings pequenas sendo verificadas poucas vezes, a diferença será imperceptível (afinal, [para poucos dados, tudo é rápido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/everything-is-fast-for-small-n/)), mas já que foi citada a "necessidade" de performance, acho que vale a pena dar alternativas (com e sem regex).

As alternativas abaixo assumem que o formato sempre é o descrito: um conjunto de caracteres sempre entre `< >`, podendo ter alguns outros antes (e talvez depois?), e no máximo somente uma ocorrência de `<` e `>` (pois também trato os casos em que não tem).

---

## Sem regex

Um jeito simples é usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) para obter os índices onde estão o `<` e `>`, e depois obter o trecho entre eles com [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
function getEmail(s) {
    // busca a posição do '<'
    var inicio = s.indexOf('<');
    if (inicio === -1) // se não tem, já retorna
        return undefined;
    // busca a posição do '>', mas começando a busca a partir da posição do '<'
    var fim = s.indexOf('>', inicio);
    if (fim === -1) // se não tem, já retorna
        return undefined;
    // retorna o trecho entre '<' e '>'
    return s.substring(inicio + 1, fim);
}

const strs = [ 'foo <foo@prov.com>', 'bar <bar@prov.com>', 'baz <baz@prov.com> fdafad fad', 'invalid' ];
const emails = strs.map(getEmail);
console.log(emails); // [ 'foo@prov.com', 'bar@prov.com', 'baz@prov.com', undefined ]
```

Ou, se quiser fazer tudo "na mão", basta um *loop* simples:

```js
function getEmail(s) {
    var inicio = null, fim = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var c = s[i];
        if (c === '<') {
            inicio = i;
        } else if (c === '>' && inicio !== null) {
            fim = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (inicio !== null && fim !== null)
        return s.substring(inicio + 1, fim);
    return undefined;
}
```

Mas acho que a versão com `indexOf` é mais simples (e também mais rápida, como veremos no final).

---

## Com regex

Se quer mesmo continuar com regex, dá para melhorar um pouco (mas não muito):

```js
const strs = [ 'foo <foo@prov.com>', 'bar <bar@prov.com>', 'baz <baz@prov.com> fdafad fad', 'invalid' ];
const emails = strs.map(str => str.match(/<([^>]+)>/)?.[1]);
console.log(emails); // [ 'foo@prov.com', 'bar@prov.com', 'baz@prov.com', undefined ]
```

A alteração está no "miolo": em vez de `.*` (que significa "zero ou mais caracteres"), usei `[^>]+`:

- o `[^>]` é uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), que significa "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `>`"
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "um ou mais" (nesse contexto eu acho melhor que `*`, que significa "zero ou mais", ou seja, também pega casos como `<>` - já o `+` obriga a ter pelo menos um caractere entre `<` e `>`)

A diferença ocorre porque os quantificadores `*` e `+` são "gananciosos" (ou "gulosos") e tentam pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. No caso, como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, então `.*` vai até o final da string (ou seja, ele também consome o `>`), e se não encontrar um *match*, ele faz o *backtracking*: começa a voltar caracteres até encontrar um *match* ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052) tem uma explicação mais detalhada sobre esse mecanismo).

Já o `[^>]+` é um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `>`, o que garante que ele vai parar antes do `>` em vez de ir até o final da string. Isso dá um ganho que pode ou não fazer diferença (no seu caso, com poucas strings pequenas, não é tanto assim, compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/AX5slG/1) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Fx87pq/1)).

---

## Comparação

[Fiz um teste](https://jsbench.me/xeksi6olml/2) comparando a regex acima, a sua, e as soluções com `indexOf` e o *loop* manual pela string ([não é algo 100% preciso](https://newbedev.com/which-js-benchmark-site-is-correct), mas dá pra ter uma ideia).

Os testes variam de uma execução para outra, mas de forma geral, as soluções com regex são mais lentas (sendo que usar `.*` na maioria das vezes se mostra mais lento).

De qualquer forma, também fiz o teste no Node (com o mesmo código do [link já citado](https://jsbench.me/xeksi6olml/2)), usando o [Benchmark.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark), e os resultados foram similares:

```
regex1 x 2,676,016 ops/sec ±1.09% (89 runs sampled)
regex2 x 2,893,208 ops/sec ±1.67% (84 runs sampled)
for x 3,191,144 ops/sec ±1.52% (83 runs sampled)
indexOf x 5,174,035 ops/sec ±1.17% (90 runs sampled)
Fastest is indexOf
```

O valor a ser considerado é o "ops/sec" (operações por segundo, ou seja, quanto maior, melhor - [claro que também tem que considerar a margem de erro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996963)). Enfim, `indexOf` é o mais rápido, e as duas regex foram mais lentas (com uma *leve* vantagem da que usa `[^>]+`).

E novamente: para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será irrelevante. Mas como a performance foi algo mencionado na pergunta, achei que valia a pena mostrar alternativas e apontar as diferenças de desempenho entre elas.