# Expressão regular para validação de e-mail e número de telefone

Tags: javascript, regex, validação

Quero fazer uma validação de e-mail e número de telefone, estou usando essa expressão para o telefone:

```
const phoneValidation = /^\([1-9]{2}\) (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

E estou usando essa expressão para validar o e-mail:

```
const emailValidation = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

Mas preciso utilizar essas duas expressões para um único input, de que maneira posso fazer isso para:

```
const emailAndPhoneValidation = ?
```

Comment: De forma geral, vc faz como a resposta abaixo (testa uma, se não der certo testa outra) ou usa alternância com o caractere `|`, algo como: `/(expressão 1)|(expressão 2)|(expressão 3)|etc/`. Mas **talvez** seja o caso de voltar alguns passos e avaliar se é uma boa usar o mesmo input para duas informações tão distintas.

Comment: Sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1386/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).

Answer (score -4):

Você pode tentar:

```
const emailAndPhoneValidation = (phoneValidation.test("input") || emailValidation.test("input"))
```