# Como criar link direto para download de um video

Tags: javascript, html, download

Bom galera, tentei criar um link direto para download de um vídeo, porém como muitos provavelmente já deve saber isso não dá muito certo. Na verdade a unica coisa que acontece quando clico sobre o link é que abre uma nova aba e o vídeo roda direto no navegador. Se eu zipar o arquivo o download funciona, porém não quero isso, como já disse no titulo da pergunta o que estou procurando é uma forma de forçar o download do vídeo e não a reprodução do mesmo.

Sobre o código que usei no link para a minha tentativa falha de criar o download não tem nenhum segredo, foi html simples.

```
<a href="video.mp4">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Comment: Tem acesso ao código do lado do servidor?

Comment: Me perdoe pela minha ignorância, mas não sei o que isso quer dizer.

Comment: Se estiver usando HTML5, poderia tentar usar o attributo `download`, sem ter que mexer no servidor. De uma olhada em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @ivanveloso, dê uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/129

Comment: walkin e Sergio, obrigado pelas informações, consegui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o atributo `download`.

```
<a download href="video.mp4">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Você pode usar o atributo para definir o nome que o arquivo deve ser salvo:

```
<a download="Férias da Família 2013.mp4" href="video.mp4">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Só funciona com navegadores atuais com suporte a HTML5.