# O que é Front-end e Back-end?

Tags: aplicação-web, front-end, back-end

Estou começando a estudar *WEB* e ainda me falta muito conhecimento, e logo de inicio me deparei com os termos que são altamente utilizados nesse mundo de desenvolvimento *WEB*, que são **Front-end** e **Back-end**, li alguns artigos a respeito, mas, mesmo assim estou com duvidas e não consigo entender esses termos. Gostaria de saber o que é **Front-end** e **Back-end**, quais sãos as linguagens e tecnologias que pertencem ao **Front-end** e qual são as que pertencem ao **Back-end** e quais são as diferenças entre eles?

Comment: Possivel dup: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/129

Comment: Nao sabia que os termos Front-end e Back-end era a mesma coisa client-side e server-side. La esta dando exemplo em ASP.NET.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho "aparentemente" dá pra trocar as duas coisas. Mas seria legal se alguém tiver uma visão diferente da coisa, compartilhar conosco. Pode ser que alguém entenda, por exemplo, que um JS funcional faça parte do back-end, mesmo estando do lado do cliente, vai saber. Terminologia aberta é sempre complicado, depende muito da maneira que as pessoas interpretam. Diferente de um termo determinado por uma RFC, por exemplo.

Comment: Bacco sugira eu marcar a pergunta como duplicada desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/27190

Comment: Já cliquei no botão e marquei como duplicata, a analogia entre servidor, cliente e usuário que o AR fez já me esclareceu muita coisa :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diferente da programação para desktops onde quase todos os recursos estão disponíveis na máquina local, na programação para web o mais importante é entender o [ciclo do protocolo http](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/91), uma requisição é feita pelo cliente o servidor processa o pedido e devolve algo (um texto, geralmente em notação html).

O termno front-end refere-se as funcionalidades desenvolvidas na parte 'cliente' do software, algumas ferramentas são javascript e css.

Back-end é termo usado para definir as funcionalidades construidas do lado do servidor.

Answer (score 5):

De maneira bem simples :

**Front-end** é o que o usuário irá visualizar, normalmente é feito em HTML e JavaScript.

**Back-end** é o que será processado por trás, no servidor. O usuário não tem acesso , o back-end é responsável também por construir o front-end para o usuário. Normalmente usa-se PHP mas pode ser feito em qualquer outra linguagem.

Answer (score 4):

Dois termos muito comuns na comunidade web e front and que voce pode se referir a client-side e back end a server-side.

Algumas linguagens como css,html e js precisam apenas do navegador do cliente para funcionar. enquanto linguagens server-side php,C# precisam de um servidor.

Recomendo a leitura de: [O que é client-side e server-side?](http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/obasico/o-que-front-back.html)

Comment: Java é linguagem front-end e back-end?

Comment: mais usada como back-end, mas se olharmos para o java applets (programas em java executados no navegador) ja é denominado front-end