# Web Frameworks: Frontend vs Backend

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, django, framework

Gostaria de saber o que caracteriza/diferencia um framework web frontend de um framework web backend. Por exemplo, Django é considerado back e Angular é considerado front, mas o que faz eles serem encaixados nestas categorias? Eu posso construir uma aplicação inteira utilizando Django ou seja, mexendo tanto com Python, requisições HTTP e banco de dados (backend) quanto mexendo com HTML, CSS e Javascript (frontend). Sendo assim, Django não deveria ser classificado como frontend também?

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/91) e [O que é Frond-end e Back-end?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105495/91)

Comment: Discordo, estou perguntando quais caracteristicas fazem um framework ser caracterizado como front ou backend

Comment: O que caracteriza um framework como back end ou front end é **onde ele trabalha**, se é do lado servidor é back end, se é no lado cliente é front end.

Comment: Você acabou de responder a pergunta. Esta informação não se encontra em nenhum dos links citados acima. Continuo discordando de duplicata.

Comment: @flpn Mas a partir do momento que você entender o que é front-end e o que é back-end, você consegue responder a pergunta sozinho, não? Sua dúvida parece vir da falta de compreensão desses termos. Por isso a marcação de duplicata.

Comment: Bem, isso depende da capacidade de dedução de cada um. No meu caso, as informações dos links acima não foram suficientes para eu chegar a uma conclusão.

Comment: Pode explicar o que faltou nos links de duplicata pra você entender?

Comment: Django não é front-end por que as única linguagens front-end são JavaScript ( e suas frameworks ), html, css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar do Javascript poder também ser usado como back-end ([NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)), no caso do `AngularJS` é usado para trabalhar os elementos de forma dinâmica. Então ele se encaixa na categoria front, pois é um framework para trabalhar **client-side**.

Agora no caso do **Django** é outra pegada. Ele não foi feito para trabalhar os elementos e sim renderizar o template e gerenciar toda estrutura dos apps do seu projeto com a ajuda das suas `models` ([ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/)), etc. É para atuar **server-side**.

### Client Side

> Cliente é um termo empregado em computação e representa uma entidade que consome os serviços de uma outra entidade servidora, em geral através do uso de uma rede de computadores numa arquitetura cliente-servidor.

Ou seja, nosso **Angular** consome um outro servidor e apresenta as informações de forma dinâmica.

### Server side

> Server-side, ou literalmente "lado do servidor", também conhecido por back-end, é um termo usado para designar operações que, em um contexto cliente-servidor, são feitas no servidor, não no cliente.

É o caso do nosso **Django**. Ele trabalha a informação e renderiza/devolve em forma de `json`, `list`, `html`, enfim, da maneira que for. Uma vez entregue na mão do **Angular**, ele não atua mais. Por exemplo, você não consegue manipular os elementos dinamicamente com Django, apenas renderizar uma vez.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]