# O que é o Node.js e o que ele substitui?

Tags: node.js

O `node.js` é o que afinal? Ele subsistitui quem?

- JavaScript?
- ServerSide?

Alguém pode me explicar melhor? Não achei na Web essas perguntas diretamente.

Comment: Substitui o PHP no server side por exemplo :P. Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/91)

Answer (score 4):

Não substitui nada. É só uma opção a mais que está disponível...

A visão extremamente simplificada do funcionamento de uma webpage é que o cliente, através de um webbrowser, solicita a página a um servidor. O servidor responde com um conteúdo em HTML e scripts em Javascript. O webbrowser mostra o HTML na tela e executa o código Javascript para fazer as partes dinâmicas da página.

Do lado do webbrowser a única linguagem de programação que roda é o Javascript enquanto do lado do servidor qualquer linguagem de programação serve (qualquer linguagem de programação é gerar de gerar um documento em formato HTML). Pode ser PHP, Python, Perl, ou praticamente qualquer outra linguagem que você quiser. Pode até ser Javascript. O Node é uma versão de Javascript com uma biblioteca padrão mais rica, com coisas que não tem no ambiente do browser, como acesso ao sistema de arquivos, bancos de dados, etc etc. Você pode usar o Node para programar um servidor web em Javascript ou simplesmente para rodar programas em Javascript no seu computador.

Comment: Node.js suporta banco de dados? MySQL etc...