# Confirmar SQL Delete usando o confirm do Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Mesmo clicando na opção *cancelar* ele faz o delete. Você podem me ajudar? 
Esse é meu codigo:

```
if (($page == 'delete') && $id > 0) {

    echo '<script>

             var r = confirm("Deseja realmente excluir esse usuário?");

             if(r != true){ return false; }else{
                 return true;
                '; 
    // executa o SQL para excluir
    $sql = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM registro.cadastro WHERE id= :id');

// prepara os dados
    $data = array(':id' => $id);

    try {
        // executa o SQL
        $sql->execute($data);

// Mostra a mensagem de erro
        $mensagem = alert('Registro deletado.');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        // mostra a mensagem
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo'}
    </script>';
}
```

Comment: Olá Danilo. Parece-me que estás a misturar PHP e JavaScript. Sabes qual a diferença entre "lado do cliente" e "lado do servidor"?  Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/129

Comment: alguém sabe uma maneira de esta fazendo essa validação?

Comment: Viste o link que te sugeri? Percebes a pergunta e respostas? (pergunto para podermos ajudar-te )

Comment: Primeiro, seguindo o comentário anterior, aconselho fazer a verificação usando Javascript, e fazer uma chamada ao PHP enviando os parâmetros para deletar após isso. Segundo, lógica. Utilize parênteses assim: if ( ($page == 'delete') && ($id > 0) ) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

**Exemplo com jQuery**

No [site oficial](http://www.jquery.com) baixe a biblioteca do jQuery e adicione à *head*:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
```

Chame a função abaixo, substitua a URL pela do seu arquivo PHP:

```
function deleta(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sim = confirm("Deletar?");
        if (sim){
            var url = "retorno.json";
            $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                if (json.status == "OK")
                    alert("Deletado!");
                else
                    console.log(json);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Seu arquivo PHP chamado na URL acima fará a operação no banco de dados, caso seja algo específico você poderá usar Ajax e um **form** e enviar parâmetros por *post*. Lembre-se de retornar um json pelo php:

```
{"status":"OK", "msg":"Sucesso!"}
```

Para isso, basta imprimir isso na tela. Não imprima nada na tela que não seja isso:

```
echo '{"status":"OK", "msg":"Sucesso!"}';
```

Se tudo der certo no *delete* imprime esse acima, caso contrário, com status "erro" no lugar do "OK".

Espero ajudar.