# Como atribuir função a um Array de Objetos?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera tenho essa função php retornando essa String:

```
function retornaGeoCod(){

    for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
        echo '{
            "lat":"-19.4746845", 
            "long":"-44.159503",
            "local":"Prudente de Morais"},';
    }
}
```

Como insiro essa função, em um array de objetos no JavaScript?

```
var array = [{}];
```

Utilizei o `json_encode` como o @ShutUpMagda sugeriu, mas agora o meu console apresenta o seguinte erro:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '>' var contentString =
>   cord$this->sc_temp_i.local;

---

Estou usando a api do google maps, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
var cord = [ <?=$this->array_push(retornaGeoCod());?> ];
```

Mas o mapa não aparece :/

Comment: Creio que você não sabe bem a diferença de **Cliente-side** e **Server-side**, Recomendo ler : [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/14213)

Comment: @gemerich, descubra como esses dados estão sendo recebidos, **mencione que está usando google maps** ao fazer a pergunta, procure compreender minimamente o funcionamento da API e o conceito de `arrays` em `PHP` e em `JavaScript`. Se não for assim, vc vai ficar perdido...

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_encode` ([manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)):

```
<?php

function retornaGeoCod() {
    $array = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
        $array[$i] = [
            "lat" => "-19.4746845", 
            "long" => "-44.159503",
            "local" => "Prudente de Morais"
        ];
        return $array;
    }
}

echo 'var array = '.json_encode(retornaGeoCod());
```