# Como popular select a partir de outro select usando python e django?

Tags: python, select, django

Boa noite pessoal!

Sou novo no fórum e comecei a fazer um pequeno projeto com python e django,
onde estou tentando preencher um select de acordo com a opção selecionada em outro. Porém, como sou iniciante, não sei como fazer isso.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
   <label id="lb-shift">Turno</label>
       <select id="p-shift" class="form-control">
        {% for course in courses %}
           <option value="{{ course.id }}">{{ course.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label id="lb-shift">Turno</label>
    <select id="p-shift" class="form-control">
        {% for turm in turms %}
             {% if turm.idCourse == "valor do outro select"%}
                <option value="{{ turm.id }}">{{ turm.name }}</option>
             {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Se for durante a interação no lado cliente, não ser feita nenhuma requisição ao servidor entre a primeira seleção e a população do segundo select deves usar é javascript, com ajax se for necessário

Comment: Os dois `select` possuem o mesmo `id`. Atente-se a isso.

Answer (score 4):

Para entender porque você não consegue implementar da maneira que tentou, apenas com Python, precisará compreender as diferenças entre *frontend* e *backend*. Talvez esta [discussão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-c%C3%B3digo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web) te ajude em algo.

Mas, basicamente o Python é executado no *backend*, entregando a resposta HTTP ao cliente, no caso, o navegador. Após a entrega da resposta, a execução é finalizada e, portanto, o Python não responderá mais à alterações na página, tal como a seleção de um item no `select`. Você pode fazê-lo responder à uma requisição assíncrona, através de AJAX, mas o mais fácil no seu caso é implementar a lógica de outra maneira, com JavaScript.

Primeiro, você define, no segundo `select`, um atributo `data-course` para cada `option`, armazenando o valor de `turn.idCourse`, da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
   <label id="lb-shift">Turno</label>
       <select id="p-shift" class="form-control">
        {% for course in courses %}
           <option value="{{ course.id }}">{{ course.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
       </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label id="lb-shift">Turno</label>
    <select id="t-shift" class="form-control">
        {% for turm in turms %}
            <option data-course="{{ turn.idCourse }}" value="{{ turm.id }}">{{ turm.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

E, com JavaScript, você observa o evento `onchange` do primeiro `select`, recupera o valor selecionado e exibe, no segundo `select`, apenas os `option` cujo o valor em `data-course` é igual ao valor selecionado.

> O código HTML utilizado abaixo é uma representação próxima ao HTML que o Python geraria de forma dinâmica e serve apenas para reproduzir o exemplo aqui.

```js
$(function () {

  // Oculta as opções do segundo select:
  $("#t-shift option").hide();
  
  // Observa o evento change do primeiro select:
  $("#p-shift").on("change", function () {
  
    // Recupera o valor selecionado:
    let course = $("#p-shift").val();
    
    // Oculta as opções atuais:
    $("#t-shift option").hide();
    
    // Exibe as opções conforme a seleção:
    $("#t-shift option[data-course="+ course +"]").show();
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label id="lb-shift">Course</label>
  <select id="p-shift" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Course 1</option>
    <option value="2">Course 2</option>
    <option value="3">Course 3</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label id="lb-shift">Turn</label>
  <select id="t-shift" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
    <option data-course="1" value="1">Turn 1</option>
    <option data-course="2" value="2">Turn 2</option>
    <option data-course="3" value="3">Turn 3</option>
    <option data-course="1" value="4">Turn 4</option>
    <option data-course="2" value="5">Turn 5</option>
    <option data-course="3" value="6">Turn 6</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Verifique que ao selecionar o *course* 1, apenas as opções `Turn 1` e `Turn 4` estarão disponíveis. Ao selecionar o *course* 2, estarão disponíveis as opções `Turn 2` e `Turn 5`. Finalmente, ao selecionar *course* 3, estarão as opções `Turn 3` e `Turn 6`.

Answer (score 1):

Um caminho (talvez o mais óbvio) é a utilização de javascript, no primeiro select você seta um onchange que chama uma função para "popular" o segundo select.

Tem [um demo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/) que se encaixa perfeitamente na sua questão, basta fazer as devidas adaptações. Não se deixe intimidar pelo código na seção javascript (parte de baixo). O cara criou arrays com vários países/estados do mundo, por isso ficou tao extenso, vá direto lá pra baixo nas duas funções (populateStates e populateCountries).

Basicamente, ele fez o seguinte, chama essas duas funções quando a página é carregada e popula os dois selects (como o pais ainda não foi escolhido, o select dos estados fica vazio), nessa ocasião, na função populateCountries ele altera o onchange do select dos países para chamar a função que popula os estados (populateStates) enviando os objetos para ela.

Tente adaptar, se não conseguir, poste aqui o problema.

> **Editado a partir de 20/03/2017 ( a partir daqui)**
>   Ok, Como combinado (nos comentários dessa resposta), gastei meu sábado para criar minha própria versão para tentar responder o que foi solicitado. A explanação aqui é somente para elucidar como foi o processo de pegar os dados do banco, passar para a template django e, por fim, entregar ao JS. O projeto (em Django), completo e funcional pode ser baixado [nesse repo github](https://github.com/Sidon/drd/).

No exemplo vamos utilizar um cadastro de veículos em uma frota (veja que não me ocupei com a gravação dos dados no banco, foquei somente no que foi solicitado na pergunta). Há dois models principais para a demonstração, um para as marcas (Brands) e outro para os modelos dos veículos (Car).

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import json

class Brand(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'brand': self.brand.company_name}
```

É importante notar que foi utilizado um artificio na funcao __str__ do model Car, para que a chamada a objects.all() retorne um dicionário com o nome e a marca dos modelos.

---

Com os models prontos, vamos à view, que o é a função principal para tornar os dados disponíveis para a template e, consequentemente, ao JS.

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Brand, Car

def regcar(request):
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    dcars = {}
    for car in cars:
        brand = str(car.brand)
        if brand in dcars:
            dcars[brand].append(car.name)
        else:
            dcars[brand] = [car.name]
    cars = json.dumps(dcars)
    brands = json.dumps([str(b) for b in brands])
    return render(request, 'core/regcar.html', {'brands': brands, 'cars': cars})
```

Essa view faz, essencialmente o seginte:

- Seleciona de models os objetos Brand (marcas) e atribui à variável
  brands;
- Seleciona de models os objetos Car (modelos) e atribui à
  variável cars;
- Converte as duas variáveis para o formato JSON;
- Renderiza a template regcar.

---

A template é muito simples, tem apenas uma div com os dois selects, devidamente identificados pelo ID. Embora aqui seja apresentado de forma separada, o script JS está incluso na template, para que seja carregado juntamente com a mesma (poderia ser através de um block, WYL.). No processo de carga, o select identificado como 'brand' será carregado por uma função JS.

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Populating a Select with Django</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Populate one dropdown based on selection in another.</h1>
        <p>Change the contents of dropdown Car based on the selection in dropdown Brand, using Django + Javascript:</p>

        <div class="select-style">
            <br />Brand:
            <select required id="brand">
            </select>

            <br />
            <br />Car:
            <select id="car" >
            </select>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

---

O código javascript é carregado juntamente com a template, nesse momento
são criadas duas variáveis que recebem os valores JSON que foram enviadas à template pela view, veja que basta fazer a atribuição normalmente, como se estivesse no python ou na própria template. Além da criação dessas variáveis, o evento onchange do select das marcas (brand) é direcionado para a função populateCar(), onde o select cujo id=car (modelos dos carros) é preenchido todas as vezes que onchange do select brand é modificado. Finalmente, a função populateBrand() é chamada para preencher o select das marcas (brand).

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#brand').change(function() {populateCar()});
    var cars = {{ cars|safe }}
    var brands = {{ brands|safe }}
    populateBrand();

    function populateBrand() {
        $("#brand").empty();
        $("#brand").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
        $.each(brands, function(v) {
            $('#brand')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", brands[v])
                .text(brands[v]));
        })
    }

    function populateCar(event) {
        brand = $("#brand option:selected" ).text();
        $("#car").empty();

        $("#car").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
        for (let [b, bcars] of Object.entries(cars)) {
            if (b==brand) {
                for (car in bcars) {
                    $('#car')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", bcars[car])
                        .text(bcars[car]));
                }
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

---

### Layout (Firefox)

[image: Resultado no Firefox]

---

### Links:

Essa mesma questão no STOen:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074402/2879341

Projeto completo em Django:
[http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/](https://github.com/Sidon/drd/)

Versão codepen:
https://codepen.io/Sidon/pen/yMpbKg

Versão Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sidon/6m1nf0zu/62/

Comment: Sua resposta não esta errada, porem veja que ele perguntou como fazer em python, o ideal seria criar a tela inicial do jeito que ele montou o select, a partir do onchange do primeiro select, chamar com js um web server que monte o segundo select, ou então com o conteúdo já renderizado em algum lugar da pagina, para quando ele alterasse, não fosse necessário consultar de novo o web server

Comment: Como a pergunta dele foi "tagueada" com Django, respondi pensando em desenvolvimento django, não é impossível mas é muito difícil desenvolver em django somente com python, tive o mesmo problema que ele e resolvi com inserção javascript. Ok, quer usar websever? Não vejo necessidade, acho que a questão é bem mais simples.

Comment: Não tenho experiencia com django, mesmo em Python minha experiencia é quase nula :P
A sugestão foi algo como renderizar os dois `selects` com todo o conteúdo, e de acordo com o selecionado no primeiro select, ir alterando o conteúdo do segundo select (dai sim com js)

Comment: Ou então usar ajax, caso o conteúdo do segundo select venha do servidor (o que parece ser o caso), ai a estrutura seria bem parecida com a que você propôs

Comment: Exatamente, na verdade o JS é somente para aproveitar o onchange, todo o resto sera feito em python, assim como é necessario usar html em django, as vezes, muitas tecnologias da plataforma web, como JS, ajax, etc, se faz necessário.

Comment: Na minha sugestão, nao importa que o conteudo venha do servidor (em django geralmente vem de um BD), vai funcionar da mesma forma, é só usar as templates do django para "renderizar" o conteudo.

Comment: Faz o seguinte: deixa o link que você postou apenas como referência e crie um exemplo verificável aqui, utilizando a mesma ideia. Isso melhorá a qualidade da sua resposta em muito.

Comment: Eheheh, até concordo @AndersonCarlosWoss, mas, na minha opinião, ganharia mais quem perguntou, se tentasse pescar ao inves de ganhar o peixe. De qualquer forma posto no fds, se for o caso.

Comment: Ok, como sugerido, criado o exemplo "verificável", utilizando a mesma ideia e postado a explicação aqui, espero que possa ajudar.