# Pegar input pela view

Tags: python, django

tenho um formulario com os inputs: email, nome e sobrenome. O email sempre terá um formato definido, então quero pegar os elementos e fazer com que preencha automaticamente nos outros campos, exemplo:

Usuário digita o email
Email: carina.joao@hotmail.com (os emails sempre terão esse formato), então quero que o form preencha nos outros campos:
Nome: carina
Sobrenome: joao

views.py

```
def cadastro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return create(request)
    else:
        return new(request)


def new(request):
    return render(request, 'cadastro1.html',
                {'form': CadastroForm()})


def create(request):
    form = CadastroForm(request.POST)
    ponto = form.email.index(".")
    arroba = form.email.index("@")
    first = form.email[0:ponto]
    second = form.email[ponto + 1:arroba]

    obj = form.save()
    if not form.is_valid():
      return render(request, 'cadastro1.html',
                    {'form': form})

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cadastro/%d/' % obj.pk)
```

Aqui já tenho o código para percorrer, porém não estou sabendo jogar nos campos

Comment: Vc quer que as informaçãoes apareçam no form enquanto o usuário digita ou basta o usuario digitar o email e vc salva diretamente no banco, sem a necessidade dos campos (nome e sobrenome) aparecerem dinamicamente para o ususário?

Comment: Aparecendo dinamicamente

Comment: Então vc vai ter que usar javascript, veja que vc não deve fazer isso no lado servidor (a view ) e  sim no lado cliente (na rendereização da template). Crie um script e carregue-o junto com a template então manipule o evento `onchange` do elemento de input do email para preencher os campos que vc deseja. Se quiser um exemplo completo, faça um clone [desse repositorio no github](https://github.com/Sidon/drd/), para reproduzi-lo passo a passo com instrucoes em portugues, veja [essa resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190406/7412)

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso, obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode capturar o campo de *email* e quebrar a *string*:

```
getEmail = request.POST['email'] #Pega o email
email = getEmail.split('@') #Quebra a string antes dps do @
nomes = email[0].split('.') #Quebra a string antes e dps do .
nome = nomes[0] #Aqui vc tem o primeiro nome
sobrenome = nomes[1] #Aqui vc tem o sobrenome
```

Agora você salva:

```
user = User()
user.email = getEmail
user.nome = nome
user.sobrenome = sobrenome
user.save()
```

Mas como disseram, a melhor opção é fazer no *front* com **js** e preencher automaticamente o form e já mandar pro *back* pronto.

Comment: Oi Flávio - você teve muito trabalho para tentar arrumar seu código, e acabou com ele pior.

Para blocos de código, simplesmente cole o código na interface, selecione ele todo, e use o botao `{ } `.  As aspas contrárias são apenas para expressões "inline".

Comment: Mas eu não tinha o código, fui digitando aqui direto baseado em algo q já tinha feito antes. kkkkkk
Mas vllw.