# django ModelForm com checkbox com valor ---------

Tags: django

Boa noite!
Como faço para remover  --------- do meu formulário, em algumas opções eu coloquei um default no model mas para esta opção eu não posso fazer isso,
como posso resolver este problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma solução seria a utilização de js na template, para isso vc teria que primeiro esvaziar o select, fazer o append do primeiro elemento assim: `append('<option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um ubc</option>')`. Faço isso em um projeto exemplo feito para uma resposta aqui no STO, se quiser ver o projeto inteiro, no final da resposta tem o link para o projeto no github. [Link para a questao](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190406/7412)

Comment: Me desculpe por responder só agora, muito obrigado pela ajuda