# Django - Dúvidas com ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando fazer um formulário em *Django*, em que eu vou salvar as versões dos projetos.

```
Exemplo:

Empresa x
    Projeto 1
         Versão 1
         Versão 2
    Projeto 2
         Versão 1
Empresa Y
    Projeto 1a
         Versão 1
...
```

Ocorre que quando vou adicionar a versão do projeto, preciso selecionar a empresa (X ou Y) e o próximo campo só pode habilitar os projetos em cada empresa.
Se eu coloco um numero fixo (1, 2, ..), o *Django* funciona, porém, preciso que esse numero seja resultado do primeiro campo.

Segue o código que escrevi:

```
class NovaEmpresa(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Projeto(models.Model):
    empresa= models.ForeignKey(NovaEmpresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sge=models.IntegerField()
    local=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        nome=str(self.empresa)+' (SGE: '+str(self.sge) +') - '+ str(self.local)
        return nome

class Versao(models.Model):
    empresa= models.ForeignKey(NovaEmpresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variavel=int(empresa) #Problema está nessa linha, não aceita a conversão de ForeignKey para Int
    projeto=models.ForeignKey(Projeto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'empresa_id': variavel},)
    #local=models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'teste'
```

Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Vc tem que fazer isso em javascript, veja o final [dessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190406/7412) tem um link para um projeto completo em django que responde a sua questão, só que ao invés de ser empresa/projeto é sobre marca/modelo de carro.

Comment: @andré-filipe top seu código, usei em parte (Html e View). Agora estou com o problema desse numero sequencial. Seria possível que nessa classe Versao, eu adicionasse um filtro em que puxaria quantas linhas existe para o campo selecionado em projeto, depois eu adiciono 1 e uso esse resultado como um models.IntegerField? Queria que quando o usuário fosse adicionar uma nova versão, automaticamente o sistema já entendesse que é a próxima versão a anterior (Exemplo: Projeto está na versão 3, quando for adicionar uma nova versão, ele já coloca versão 4).

Answer (score 0):

Analisando sua arquitetura. Se o mesmo projeto não pode estar em mais de uma empresa e uma versão pertence apenas a um projeto, é possivel eliminar o campo "empresa" do objeto Versão. Tornando desnecessaria a verificação da empresa do projeto na versão.

Comment: Nesse caso, é necessário. Imagine que quero adicionar a Versao 2 ao projeto 1a, para isso, basta eu encontrar o projeto 1a na lista de cadastro (Admin). O que acontece que é o numero da versão (1, 2, sequencial), não pode ser inputado pelo usuário (Campo IntegerField), porque senão, pode ocorrer dele criar duas versões 1 para o mesmo projeto, o que seria uma falha do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema.

É possível executar uma função antes de salvar, sendo assim, o código ficou:

```
class Versao(models.Model):
    projeto=models.ForeignKey(Projeto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    local=models.FileField()
    num_versao=models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.projeto) + '_V' + str(self.num_versao)

    def save(self, force_update=False, force_insert=False):
        qtd_versoes=Versao.objects.filter(projeto=self.projeto).count()
        self.num_versao=qtd_versoes+1
        super(Versao, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```