# Quais as diferenças entre client-side e server-side "rendering"?

Tags: lado-do-servidor, lado-do-cliente

Ultimamente tenho visto bastante o termo `server-side rendering`, principalmente com a popularização de alguns frameworks e bibliotecas, porém ainda não consigo entender quais melhorias isso pode trazer em um sistema.

Gostaria de saber as diferenças entre esses dois tipos de renderizações e também os prós e contras dos mesmos.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/3635)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Renderização Server Side

O servidor processa os dados solicitados, gera a página e transmite ao cliente a página pronta em HTML. O navegador lê o HTML e "desenha" a página para a pessoa.

**Prós:**

- O servidor é uma máquina com grande capacidade de processamento e o processamento maior fica no servidor
- Cliente não precisa preocupar muito com processamento dos dados, somente com a recepção e exibição da página em si.

**Contras:**

- Toda a página pronta deve ser transmitida via rede/internet. Isso aumenta o uso de banda.
- Sempre que necessário algum processamento, o cliente chama o servidor que faz novamente todo o processo, gerando nova página no servidor que será retransmitida totalmente para o cliente. Tal processo exige mais banda de rede/internet.

### Renderização Client Side

O cliente envia solicitação dos dados desejados e renderiza a página por si mesmo. Somente os dados são recebidos, o cliente tem o trabalho de gerar a página a ser exibida no navegador.

**Prós**:

- Não é necessário transferir toda a página via rede/internet a cada alteração. Somente os novos dados são transferidos.
- Não sobrecarrega tanto o servidor em caso de muitos clientes.

**Contras**

- Aumenta o processamento do lado do cliente, exigindo talvez uma máquina melhor nos clientes. Alterar a página pelo cliente é um procedimento que naturalmente gasta muitos recursos. Usar demasiadamente causa lentidão.
- Aplicações do lado cliente (javascript) expõem o código da aplicação cliente.

---

### Opinião pessoal

Na minha opinião, o interessante é gerar inicialmente a primeira página no lado do servidor e as alterações/atualizações gerar do lado do cliente.

Comment: Obrigado Shura, bem esclarecedor

Answer (score 6):

Isto é sobre quem monta o conteúdo a ser apresentado.

Se for no servidor obviamente ele tem todo o trabalho de montar um texto que será a página a ser entregue para o cliente, essencialmente pronta para uso.

Se for no cliente, um conjunto de página mais códigos diversos será recebido pelo cliente e a partir daí ele só comunicará com o servidor para pedir novas informações que precise, tudo o que precisa modificar e adaptar na apresentação da página ocorre no cliente mesmo.

Há casos híbridos.

Obviamente que desenhar tudo no cliente pode descarregar um pouco a necessidade do servidor trabalhar. Em tese, porque dependendo do caso fazer várias solicitações isoladas pode gerar tanta carga que pode ser pior que renderizar no servidor. Sem falar que o desenvolvedor pode fazer tudo errado e piorar a situação.

Renderizar no cliente pode trazer mais insegurança, quebra de privacidade, pirataria do código. Claro que maioria dessas coisas podem ser resolvidas com algum trabalho.

Renderização em cliente não costuma se dar muito bem com SEO, mesmo que algumas pessoas acreditem que não tem problema, ou seja, não costuma ser muito bom para websites. Funciona melhor e tem mais vantagens em aplicações web que são bem diferentes.

Por incrível que pareça não há controle tão bom renderizando no cliente, pelo menos no estado atual da tecnologia.

Quando manda tudo para o cliente é comum ter uma carga inicial grande, em alguns casos os usuários podem ter que ficar esperando vários segundos até poder usar a página inicial. Mas depois pode ser melhor porque fica parecido com uma aplicação normal e não tem tempo de carga excessivo para troca de telas.

Tenho visto as pessoas criarem as duas coisas porque uma resolve melhor alguns aspectos no servidor e outros no cliente. Então dá mais trabalho, mas acabam tendo tudo o que oferece o SSR e o CSR.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando tiver um tempinho termina a resposta rs

Comment: @DiegoAugusto tá complicado, muita coisa aparecendo e isso preciso de um tempo, ainda estão me pentelhando e eu estou gastando tempo com coisa pouca produtiva. Tem hora que dá vontade de largar tudo de qq jeito, aí ficam reclamando sozinho que ninguém faz nada. Mas vou terminar sim, se não hoje, amanhã, ela tá aberta inclusive

Comment: Tranquilo, deve ser difícil mesmo kk, vou esperar :D