# Como fazer o CSS ocultar uma rotina PHP

Tags: php, css

Preciso que uma rotina `PHP` seja ocultada e exibida uma outra, utilizando `CSS`. Pois tenho uma rotina em `PHP` que gera números de colunas para exibir minhas informações, mas será necessário que quando o navegador estivem com certa largura o número de colunas seja alterado.

Veja abaixo meu PHP com CSS:

```
<span class="mobile_detect">
<?php
$colunas = 3;
?> 
</span>
```

Acima é o que preciso. Mas não está funcionando, ele continua atribuindo o número 3 à variável quando o navegador é redimensionado. Se eu remover o script `PHP` e colocar um texto, por exemplo, ele oculta tranquilamente. Só não está ocultando o script `PHP`.

**CSS**

```
.mobile_detect{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: `$colunas = 3;` só define a variável não escreve nada nesse local. Para isso será preciso um `echo`. Redimensionamento tem de vir de [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). O que significa que o php terá que escrever cada valor especifico dentro de cada media query.

Comment: @Isac Olá, toda  a rotina com `@media Queries` está funcionando perfeitamente. Este é apenas um trecho. Se eu remover o script PHP e colocar um texto, por exemplo, ele oculta tranquilamente. Só não está ocultando o script PHP. E não sei o porque!

Comment: Ocultar o script de php ? como assim? O script nunca é visível na página ,apenas o seu resultado, ou seja os valores que produziu.

Comment: Você precisa estudar o que é *client-side* e o que é *server-side*. [Aqui tem uma pergunta para começar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/5878).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ele continua atribuindo o número 3 à variável quando o navegador é redimensionado

O que você quer é impossível. A atribuição do valor à variável acontece antes de qualquer coisa ser exibida na tela - e não muda. Quando o processamento do PHP termina e o HTML é enviado para o navegador, nada mais pode ser alterado.

Já o CSS é aplicado após o HTML ser renderizado no navegador, ou seja, bem depois da lógica que você determinou ali.

Você precisa alterar a lógica do seu programa pra não depender de uma variável em PHP quando precisar modificar o layout. Pode fazer essa atribuição em Javascript por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

se eu entedi bem voce ta querendo ocultar o codigo gerado pelo script ate que seja redimensionado, não seja exibido nem no codigo fonte, seria isso? ou o codigo php esta sendo exibido mesmo com o css para ele ficar oculto?

tipo se for para não exibir ele no codigo fonte ate o momento que for redimensionado voce vai ter que fazer uma requisição para o servidor novamente pedido o trecho da pagina usando ajax ou ate mesmo iframe, vamos ver um exemplo mais simples, um div onde não tem nada escrito quando aperta o botão ele puxa essa informação do servidor e monta sem sair da propria pagina

codigo html

```
<html>
<script>
  function kodo_puxar(){
     //aqui ele pega o div pelo id
     var meudiv = document.getElementById("kami");
     //instanciamos o objeto
     var meureq = new XMLHttpRequest();
     //especificamos a url e o metodo
     meureq.open("get","http://192.168.1.1/kodo/puxar.php",false);
     //fazemos a requisição
     meureq.send();
     //jogamos a resposta no div
     meudiv.innerHTML = meureq.responseText;
  }
</script>
<body>
<h1>exemplo stackoverflow by kodo</h1><hr>
<div id="kami">
</div>
<input type="button" value="puxar" onclick="kodo_puxar()">
</body>
</html>
```

no codigo php a gente gera o html

```
<?php
  echo '<font color="red">testando</font>';
?>
```

se a gente olhar na pagina (codigo fonte) o codigo do php não foi gerado ainda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem quando apertamos o botão é feito a requisição no servidor puxado o novo codigo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

voce pode por exemplo passar como argumento a dimensão da pagina e criar o codigo html novamente com base nele apenas se estiver no tamanho desejado, voce pode usar eventos para saber quando foi redimensionado ou na gambiarra usando setInterval, como tambem é possivel fazer isso diretamente no javascript (porem nesse caso o cliente vai ter acesso aos dados do codigo fonte)