# PHP Javascript - Erro no IF

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com o código abaixo, porém ele não está obedecendo a comparação dos `if`'s, sempre coloca o último valor mesmo sem passar por ele, segue código:

```
<?php $minhavar = 100; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Teste</h1>
<p>Trocar valor da variavel php</p>

<form name="form1">

<input type ="text" id="varhtml" value = 1 >

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

</form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {

var item = form1.varhtml.value;

if (item == 1){
            alert("<?php
              $minhavar = 1200;
            echo $minhavar; ?>") ;    
}

if (item == 2){
            alert("<?php
              $minhavar = 2200;
            echo $minhavar; ?>") ;

}

if (item == 3){
            alert("<?php
              $minhavar = 3200;
            echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
}

//sempre esta mostrando o ultimo valor mesmo o item nao sendo 3
 alert("<?php echo $minhavar; ?>") ;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "entrou na funcao javascript";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

O problema continua (preciso trocar o valor da variavel PHP `$minhavar`) ver código abaixo:

```
<?php
$minhavar = 100;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>teste</h1>
<p>trocar valor da variavel php</p>

<form name="form1">
<input type ="number" id="varhtml" name = "varhtml" value = 1 >
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<button onclick="vervalor()">Ver Valor variavel </button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>

     function myFunction() {
                    var item = form1.varhtml.value;

                    if (item == 1) {
                        alert("<?php $minhavar = 1200; echo $minhavar; ?>");
                    }
                    else if (item == 2){
                        alert("<?php $minhavar = 2200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
                    }
                    else if (item == 3){
                        alert("<?php $minhavar = 3200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
                    }
                }

    function vervalor(){
        alert("<?php  echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
        }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente o problema é que não é possível determinar o valor da variável PHP `$minhavar` com o `if` do JavaScript.

> Quando fui ver no view-souce da pagina ele ja executa todos os `<?php` e
>   sempre prevalece o ultimo.

Isso ocorre porque o PHP (que é server side) não interpreta (não executa os comandos) do que está fora das tags `<?php  ?>`, ou `<?  ?>` (e o que está dentro de comentários).

Para o PHP, tudo que está fora destas tags (ou dentro de comentários) simplesmente "não existe" (como comandos). Todo este `if/else` do JavaScript é apenas um "texto qualquer" que será enviado para o navegador sem sofrer alteração pelo interpretador do PHP.

Este é o código que o PHP enviou para  o navegador renderizar:

```
function myFunction() {

            var item = form1.varhtml.value;

            if (item == 1) {
                alert("1200");
            }
            else if (item == 2){
                alert("2200") ;
            }
            else if (item == 3){
                alert("3200") ;
            }

        }
```

Exatamente o que você mandou ele fazer quando disse que `$minhavar` valia `x` (`$minhavar = 1.200` p.ex) e deu um `echo` (mandou escrever) logo em seguida.

Quem vai interpretar o que está dentro das tags `<script> </script>` é o navegador (client side). Aqui tem uma boa pergunta com algumas ótimas respostas sobre a diferença entre server side e client side: [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/23400)

Resumindo, não é possível mudar o valor de uma variável PHP em decorrência de uma condição de um código JavaScript, porque o primeiro roda no servidor (e não entende as tag `<script>`) e o segundo no cliente.

Na verdade, mesmo no código original o primeiro `alert` é sempre de acordo com o que você selecionou, e apenas o último (no final da função) é que aparece sempre com 3.200.

Quando você faz:

```
 if (item == 1) {
   alert("<?php $minhavar = 1200; echo $minhavar; ?>");
    }
 if (item == 2){
    alert("<?php $minhavar = 2200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
    }
 if (item == 3){
    alert("<?php $minhavar = 3200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
    }
```

O PHP simplesmente vai estar redeclarando a variável `$minhavar` com outro valor (primeiro 1.200, depois 2.200, e por fim 3.200).

Para obter o resultado esperado (ou seja, para o `alert` aparecer com o valor esperado), apenas retire o último `alert()`, e troque os dois últimos `ifs` por `else ifs`.

Mas repare que **o valor da variável, ao final do script, será sempre 3.200**, não importa o valor que você selecione no JS.

```
<script>

 function myFunction() {

        var item = form1.varhtml.value;

        if (item == 1) {
            alert("<?php $minhavar = 1200; echo $minhavar; ?>");
        }
        else if (item == 2){
            alert("<?php $minhavar = 2200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
        }
        else if (item == 3){
            alert("<?php $minhavar = 3200; echo $minhavar; ?>") ;
        }

    }

</script>

<?php echo $minhavar; ?> // saída é sempre R$ 3.200
```

Comment: Bom Dia Gustavo, continua com o mesmo problema. o que preciso é trocar o valor de uma variavel PHP $minhavar dependendo do valor escolhido. Quando fui ver no view-souce da pagina ele ja executa todos os <?php e sempre prevalece o ultimo. vou deixar o novo codigo abaixo para voce ver com um botao para mostra o valor atual da variavel PHP $minhavar.

Comment: Vi que os IFs ele ate executa corretamente o problema esta nas instrucoes <?php que sao executadas logo quando chamo a pagina.

Comment: @mariofel Editei a resposta tentando esclarecer as dúvidas do seu comentário. Da forma como você está querendo fazer, acredito que não seja possível.

Comment: Gustavo, valeu. Vou criar um outro .PHP e enviar via POST e la monto a minha logica. Obrigado.

Comment: @mariofel Não entendi muito bem qual o resultado final que vc quer, o comportamento que espera da aplicação. Se for apresentar os dados na mesma página dá pra fazer só com o JS. Se precisar gravar no bd dá pra fazer com `ajax`, tudo sem precisar de `post`, sem dar reload na página ou abrir outra... o que não dá é pra mudar o valor da variável do PHP pelo if do JS... Mas blz, se resolveu então tranquilo. abs