# Hoje em dia.. até onde vai o front-end?

Tags: angular, front-end, framework, back-end, teoria-da-computação

antes de marcarem como duplicada da seguinte pergunta *[Diferença entre client-side e server-side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-c%C3%B3digo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web)*.

Vamos analisar uns fatos.

A pergunta anterior é de 2013 ou seja 4 anos atrás, muito antes da ascensão dos frameworks javascript *"reativos"*.

- **Angular JS** = primeira aparição **2010**
- **Express.js** = primeira aparição **2010**
- **Elm** = primeira aparição = **2012**
- **React** = primeira aparição = **2013**
- **Ionic** = primeira aparição = **2013**
- **Angular** = primeira aparição **2014**
- **Vue.js** = primeira aparição **2014**

Isto que estamos falando apenas de frameworks web, hoje em dia sabemos que javascript não é mais terra sem lei, a linguagem evoluiu e hoje roda tanto no **server-side** como no **client-side**.

Então pode parecer uma duvida besta, mas hoje por exemplo o angular é composto por 3 arquivos principais em seu "core".

- **HTML**
- **TypeScript**
- **SASS / CSS**

sabemos que o angular é composto por diversas categorias de arquivos responsáveis por alguma parte da aplicação.

- Component
- Service
- Class
- Directive
- Guard
- Interface
- Pipe
- Module

Esses são alguns arquivos que podem fazer parte de um projeto angular.

Então hoje em dia...

- um desenvolvedor front-end deve saber manipular todo o ecossistema do framework web ?
- ele é responsável por conectar o back-end com o front-end (usando por exemplo os services) ?
- ele é responsável por deixar as telas funcionais e dinâmicas ?
- ou ele é simplesmente responsável por fazer apenas o visual (ux) ?

Comment: Eu ainda não tenho certeza se a pergunta merece mesmo ser fechada definitivamente, mas fechei preventivamente porque este tipo de pergunta tende a atrair respostas ruins, inclusive porque se muda dependo do dia que está lendo a resposta, ela não é boa mesmo. Na forma atual não está boa e parte de premissas erradas, ambíguas, e não sei se ela sequer está no escopo e não sei se dá para responder isto porque provavelmente não há resposta universal. Aguardo outras opiniões e quem sabe melhorias que podem salvá-la. O assunto não é ruim.

Comment: Concordo com o fechamento, pq todos os assuntos discutidos são muito mais amplos do que as premissas que o autor pôs. Foram citados como referencias uma meia duzia de frameworks web que estão na moda, mas que estão longe de representar tudo que engloba front-end e UI (inclusive até diria que alguns são referências ruins). Seria melhor editar ou refazer a pergunta tratando ponto a ponto e elegendo o ambiente específico de cada caso (ou grupo de ambientes familiares). Inclusive, diria que as melhores experiências de front end para web (que já são bem restritas) não usam nada disso aí.