# Passar variável de SELECT sem reload e sem submit

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select

Gostaria de passar uma variável de um select para outra página e sem botão de submit. Isso é possível?

Aqui o código do select (que está na página **"index.php"**:

```
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="plano" class="form-label">Plano:</label>
                <select name="plano" id="plano" class="form-select" required>
                    <option value="" class="fs-4">Selecione</option>
                    <option value="planoa" class="fs-4">Plano A</option>
                    <option value="planob" class="fs-4">Plano B</option>
                    <option value="planoc" class="fs-4">Plano C</option>
                    <option value="planod" class="fs-4">Plano D</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Aqui o código da página que quero receber a variável **(listar_proc.php)**:

```
$queryProc = "SELECT id_proc, desc_proc, tuss, valor_proc FROM $variavel WHERE desc_proc LIKE :desc_proc LIMIT 100";
```

Basicamente, o que eu quero fazer é que quando o usuário escolha uma opção do select no **index.php**, seja enviado o valor para uma variável para a página **listar_proc.php** sem atualizar a página **index.php**, porque dependendo da escolha o usuário, a query (da pag listar_proc.php) irá apontar para diferentes tabelas do banco de dados.

Por exemplo, se o usuário seleciona "Plano B", o valor "planob" é enviado para a $variavel na listar_proc.php, e a $queryProc passa a utilizar o valor "planob" após o **FROM**.

Explicando porque quero fazer isso: os próximos campos deste formulário (no index.php), terão searchs no banco de dados, e não posso misturar as tabelas no DB. Quando o usuário selecionar Plano A, o DB só vai retornar resultados da tabela o Plano A.

Isso é possível?

Comment: Dá uma lida nessa pergunta que mesmo sendo ASP.NET o conceito serve para PHP e eu acho que você está fazendo uma confusão com o conceito: [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/137387) leia esse também [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/137387).

Comment: Já ouviu falar em AJAX?

Answer (score -4):

você pode fazer um requisição usado javascript para `listar_proc.php`, dai no `listar_proc.php` você retornaria um json com os dados do plano

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#plano');

select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
   const plano = event.target.value
  window.alert(`request to listar_proc.php send plano: ${plano}`)

 
// fetch('/listar_proc.php', {
//    method: 'POST',
//    body: '{plano: 'A'}',
// })
// .then( r => r.json)
// .then(data => {
//    você receberia os dados aqui
// })
})
```

```html
<select name="plano" id="plano" class="form-select" required>
  <option value="" class="fs-4">Selecione</option>
  <option value="planoa" class="fs-4">Plano A</option>
  <option value="planob" class="fs-4">Plano B</option>
  <option value="planoc" class="fs-4">Plano C</option>
  <option value="planod" class="fs-4">Plano D</option>
</select>
```

`